# Router with base64 generated param

Tags: node.js, geddy

I am trying to send a parameter after convert it to the base 64 the definition of the `geddy.js` `route` :

```
router.get(routing_prefix+'/gogetthecart/:data').to('Main.gogetthecart');
```

In the client side, javascript, I generate a `base64` json data `var jsonb64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(params));` after that I call the url that will somthing like this

```
http://www.mydomain.com//gogetthecart/GVudGl...aWNo=
```

I got **Error: 404 Not Found**.. But If I delete manually the **`=`** from the end of data that work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by the community in the git repos issues https://github.com/geddy/geddy/issues/556 as Kieran said

> I looked into adding support for base64 encoded vars to Barista
>   directly, but some characters in the b64 spec are reserved in the URI
>   spec. I don't feel comfortable making that the default behaviour.
>
> However! You can simply override the behaviour to support this use
>   case:
>
> ```
> router
> .get( routing_prefix+'/gogetthecart/:data')
> .to('Main.gogetthecart')
> .where({
>   data: /[\w\-\/+]+={0,2}/ // base64-safe regex condition
> })
> ```
>
> and that should do the trick!
>
> I added a test here:
>   https://github.com/kieran/barista/blob/master/tests/barista.test.js#L812